# Gnome 3.16 HiDPI scaling only accepts integers

Tags: gnome, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome, scaling

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 with Gnome 3.16, which is working really great on my machine (despite what I found on many forums around the web). Having a high DPI screen however (13.3" with 1920x1080) I need to scale the entire system to use it. There is a setting for that in the TweakTool, but it only seems to accept integers as scaling factor.

[image]

Does anybody know about a workaround for this? Scaling by two is way too large for my screen. The value I want is closer to 1.2

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may find some clues in the [archlinux tutorial on the subject](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI)

Answer (score 1):

I checked with my Fedora 21 install where I have Gnome 3.14.2 and it doesn't seem to be possible to set your desired value:

```
[btegge@za21 ~]$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1.2
invalid character in number:
  1.2
   ^
[btegge@za21 ~]$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1,2
expected end of input:
  1,2
   ^
```

My assumptions:

- There is a another setting to achieve what you want. The only thing that comes to my mind is font rendering related, though that is not exactly what you are looking for.
- It's a mistake that the key only accepts integers as datatype and you should file a bug.

Comment: Thats the exact same error I get as well

Comment: Gnome only accepting integer scaling factors is a known limitation even now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this got resolved or not, but there are two scaling options in Gnome to achieve this. The "window scaling" attribute that you are doing either accepts 1 or 2 (or 0, but this is "undefined" I think). If you want, you can do text scaling, which accepts floating numbers.

In Gnome Tweak Tool, this is available under the font section. Alternatively, you can access both in the dconf-editor under `org.gnome.desktop.interface` I have noticed this option tends to work better, as Gnome Tweak Tool can sometimes not update setting correctly, causing weird scaling issues.

Answer (score 1):

Fractional scaling is [not officially supported](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GNOME-3.32-Fractional-Scaling) on versions lower than `3.32` and not supported at all inside GNOME in versions lower than `3.28`.

You can neverthless obtain the same effect on 3.16 with [xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Fractional_Scaling).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you switch to the Wayland display server:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome-linux

Otherwise, your only option would seem to be to upgrade to a version of the distro with a newer version of GNOME. This functionality is available in Ubuntu 19.04:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-fractional-scaling-ubuntu-19-04

Answer (score -1):

Non-integer scaling is not (yet) supported in Gnome and therefore Ubuntu. Athough, it is possible to achieve with some workarounds using xrandr, which involves an upscaling and a subsequent downscaling, I cannot recommend this as it is very CPU/GPU intensive and comes with other quirks and problems and does not necessarily lead to the desired result. There are a lot of ongoing debates and argues on r/linux over at reddit if you are interested and here is also an article from one of the elementary devs (a distro based on Ubuntu) who talks a bit more about High DPI in depth: [link](https://medium.com/elementaryos/top-3-misconceptions-about-hidpi-f5ef493d7bf8). Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: As of Gnome 3.28 it actually is possible now, but thx for your comment.

Comment: @Severin Correct me if I am mistaken, but doesn't Gnome 3.28 only support fractional scaling via a Wayland session in an experimental feature, i.e. it is not supported officially, yet? (see [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04) )
Concerning "this does not provide an answer to the question". I think it does. If it is not supported in 3.28, it certainly is not in 3.16. How to work around it? I mentioned the procedure using xrandr. I think this can still be a valid workaround for OP. I should have provided a source, though. Sorry.