# Where to scale interface in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, display-resolution, scaling

Unlike the previous 16.04, in 18.04 I cannot see anywhere where to scale the interface.

As the latest thousand thread on "Interface scale on Ubuntu" I'm running on a 4k gaming laptop with Ubuntu as a virtual machine on the latest VMware Player.

I actually have seen just a few ways to deal with it by running by instance `xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 2x2` or just enable the feature by `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"` but in my case nothing happened with both.

I backed up on the 16.04 but after days of search and I wonder if it's a 18.04 feature -or- something that cannot be changed on 18.04 when running on a VM (thought Unity lasted since Ubuntu 17 so that could be the reason why I can make it on 16.04?).

Any advice?

Main references:

[Enable fractional scaling for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04)

[Enable fractional scale on GNOME](https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome/)

[EDIT]
Found something more about [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome-linux) and had given another try and by running the command to enable `scale-monitor-framebuffer` it seemed that something happened but once returned on the "Display" window the "scale" section under the dropdown of the resolution did not appear.

Also tryed by running `sudo gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"` with sudo privileges and returned me `(process:7676): dconf-WARNING **: 12:32:40.213: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=95a7941a7aa3477dacf239b1a2ba24a8 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1`

Comment: Are you selecting X or Wayland at login? To use X tools, you must select X.

Comment: Actually I don't know what's X but yes, I'm with Wayland.

Comment: Login using the non-Wayland option. X is the older window server, and that's what Xrandr and similar tools expect.

Comment: Ok, just logged on Ubuntu non-wayland, run the same `xrandr` command but still nothing happends. Do you suggest me anithing else? Could be something related to the fact that is running on a VM (on VMWare Player)?