# How to scale second monitor resolution using xrandr

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have a 3840x2160 laptop that I wish to connect to a 3440x1440 monitor, but the scaling on one of them will either be too small or too big using the Ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) screen display settings.

I followed the instructions found here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Multiple_displays

and ran the command:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto --output DP-2 --auto --panning 3840x2160+3840+0 --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP-1
```

but the output was this:

```
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 8192x8192 (desired size 10720x2880)
```

Running `xrandr -q` results in this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97    48.00  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3440x1440     49.99 +
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: As you're on Ubuntu 18.04, have you tried using Wayland? See the second half of this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1030032/8989 (that answer also has suggestions for `xrandr` settings)