# Changing the size of the theme icons

Tags: 18.04, gnome, icons, themes, icon-themes

I'm trying to get a good looking desktop on a mid-DPI monitor (27" 4k), where 100% scale is to little and 200% is too much. I've been able to get a decent result by font scaling (1.5) and application theme tweaking (the screenshot shows a modified version of the [Sierra](https://github.com/vinceliuice/Sierra-gtk-theme) GTK theme), but here is the question:

Is there a way to customize the size of the stock icons shown in applications, in particular all the black ones from the screenshot below? They look tiny compared to the text next to them.

[image: Screenshot]
I've figured they come from the icon theme, and the icon theme I'm using ([La Capitaine](https://github.com/keeferrourke/la-capitaine-icon-theme)) provides two icon sizes: 16 and 24. It seems the 16 pixel version is used here. Is there a way to select the other icon size? Or to add an intermediate size (by editing the theme and scaling the icons) and then make sure it's used?

Comment: I'm surprised 150% scaling isn't available. According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029436/301745) it's not. So maybe you could go up to 200% and scale everything else *down* instead?

Comment: That would create the opposite problem, since font scaling does not affect all UI elements: the icons would be larger than the text, title bars would be huge, etc. Additionally, 200% is worse since it relies on themes/apps having 2x versions for their icons, and if they don't then you get blurry (scaled up) icons. Also, you lose one of the perks of high-ish DPI: really thin lines in the theme (1px), as now they get doubled.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to edit the `index.theme` file in the theme directory, and increase (to 24) the value of the `MinSize` and `Size` settings for the `*/symbolic` icons entries.