# Mirror Displays of 2 different resolutions

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics, 4k-monitor

I am wanting to mirror asymmetrically whereby the main monitor is a lower resolution than the HD TV we are using as a monitor.  When the displays are in non-mirrored mode (spanning?) each monitor display properties allows me to set the resolution the the maximum of each monitor.  When I switch to mirroring the HD TV drops down to the lower setting on the main monitor.

If it is not possible to do with one video card perhaps I can use both my video cards?

AMD Radeon Pro WX 2100 (active)

Intel UHD Graphics 630 (not active)

4K HD TV - 3840x2160

Dell 30" monitor - 2560x1600
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I may just order a 4K 32" monitor and call it a day mirror on the same high resolution ... maybe xrandr or something?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am trying two answers (it does not help you are not mentioning your OS). I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I am using a dual monitor set-up. In Ubuntu it is called *Join Displays*. I am not using Mirror.
Both monitor (27"/28") keep their native resolution (1920x1080,3840x2160).
Problem is hidpi monitors are not well supported yet and usually trying to scale one monitor affects the other one as well.
Following https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI helped to work around that problem.

Comment: There is already a better answer here: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04)