# 19.10 laggy & unstable. 18.04 lacks fractional scaling. What should i do?

Tags: 18.04, display, performance, 19.10, scaling

I have an [Asus Vivobook s13](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S13-S330UN/Tech-Specs/) running on an [Intel i3 8145u APU w/ HD 620 graphics](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/137977/intel-core-i3-8130u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html). I'm a frontend dev and need Ubuntu for development. But, Ubuntu 18 doesn't have fractional scaling; the 13" FHD monitor has no fractional scaling ability.

I installed 19.10, but running it, my battery dropped from 100 to 0% in one hour; with basic use it gets very hot and the notebook fans work hard even when I use just Chrome. Moreover, with Chrome and VS Code system starts to freeze.

Now after Windows 10 I don't have really good and comfort Linux solution for me with 13" FHD laptop with normal optimisation and fractional scaling. Why does Windows 10 works well on my laptop, while Ubuntu is so unusable?

p.s. After Windows 10 I noticed Ubuntu's interface is laggy,  and on 19.10 it has problems with vsync.

Comment: What graphics card the laptop has; If invida try installing the propriatery drivers.

Comment: @K7AAY why you eddited my post. :))) i don't have NVIDIA card. There is just intel uhd graphics 620.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S13-S330UN/Tech-Specs/ says you do have an NVIDIA GeForce MX150 w/ 2GB dedicated DDR5 VRAM. - see Graphics section. Installing the NVIDIA proprietary video drivers would boot your performance, and your laptop may run cooler. Or, do you have a different ASUS VivoBook?

Comment: @K7AAY yes i have different version with 8 GB of RAM and with stock video card.

Comment: Well, then how about clicking [edit] and putting the model number into your question, so accurate information is available to those who are trying to help?  Please provide the model number as shown on the serial number sticker; any model number anywhere else isn't going to assure us of getting the right info. Please do not answer us with Add Comment as it looses all formatting; instead, please click [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop is the slowest Asusbook 13; all other models have better processors. The Windows drivers for every function in it have been optimized by the world's largest software company, whereas Ubuntu development is predominantly a labor of love. Asus does not provide support for Ubuntu, either, so it's not surprising you may have to make changes to improve performance.

Next, look at alternative desktop environments which are available as supported Ubuntu 'flavours'; see and download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .  GNOME3 is [heavy and slow by comparison to all the alternatives](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubu-1704-desktops&num=1).

Comment: Thanks. But now I'm working on 18.04 and it works 100% perfect in terms of performance and power consumption. I think it's some problems with 19.10 drivers for intel hd graphics. I don't know why, but 18.04 works super fast and my laptop feels very comportable on 18.04. but without scaling i can't use it (((

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04 for a discussion of multiple solutions for scaling (including using a different flavor of 18.04).