# Extreme Resolution with Ubuntu 20 update

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

I just updated to Ubuntu 20.04, and my laptop's Nvidia GTX 1650 Driver (440) has caused my screen's resolution to go to 3840 x 2160 - WOW!  Everything is sharpe and crisp and clear, but some of my apps are having a hard time adjusting - either I need a magnifying glass, or they become oversized depending on scaling.  Usually, I would simply choose less of a resolution, but I am not able to.  Only resolution is the 3840 x 2160.  Any idea on how to bring it down?

Comment: Does [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04) help at all?

Comment: Thanks @DankyNanky, but not really.  The issue is that I cannot reduce the resolution.  I can use fractional scaling, but that doesn't solve the problem that the intense resolution is causing some programs to "freeze," and others are distorted.  Something weird about the only resolution selection.