# Dual Monitor Nvidia GeForce GTX660 | Window Maximize

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, maximized

Currently I have two monitors plugged into the two DVI connectors on an nVIDIA GeForce GTX660 GPU.  When I maximise a windows of a programme, it stretches across **both** monitors.  I would like to have a maximised window just on ***one*** monitor.  How do I do that?  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked under : Settings -> Devices -> Screen Display and check the setup that you have.

Also try the solution here in case it helps with your display issues, it certainly helped with mine:
[Enable fractional scaling for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Yes, that is all set-up correctly.  I believe it's an nvidia-settings, or else </etc/X11/xorg.conf> file setting.