# How to adjust the VirtualBox to show the 'fractional scaling' on ubuntu setting page?

Tags: virtualbox, display, scaling

I use VirtualBoxVM on my MacOS. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox. I want to show `'fractional scaling'` like physical ubuntu environment as below.

[image: Screenshot showing fractional scaling option]

But there are no `'fractional scaling'` on VirtualBox.

[image: Screenshot not showing fractional scaling option]

What to do for it?

Comment: Fractional scaling was not fully implemented in 18.04. That said, [the answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029436/1222991) may help you resolve the issue you're facing 