# Tiny icons in Gnome/GTK apps

Tags: gnome, icons

- I'm running Ubuntu 22/Gnome 42.2/Wayland.
- I've set my display for 100% scaling.
- I used Tweak Tool to set my font scaling to 2.0

The icons for Gnome desktop are almost too small, and the icons for applications like Gimp and Pinta are to small to be useful. I'm using my laptop monitor and the Pinta icons shown in the image below are actually much smaller than on my screen. Tweak Tool does not have an option to scale icons, like it does for fonts.

How do I "scale up the icons" to a useful size?

[image]

Comment: You cannot. Try 200% scaling and reducing the font size. Also fractional scaling is possible, and may work better with Wayland than with Xorg.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable fractional scaling for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Thanks. The problem for me is the mismatch between font and icon sizes between applications. GNOME Desktop, Firefox, Chrom, and IntelliJ look great. Pinta, Drawing, Libre Office, and Gimp have tiny icons.